# Automorphisms of strictly ergodic shift spaces

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics

Let $X$ be a *strictly ergodic* shift space, and $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ be two different points in $X$. Is there an automorphism $\Psi$ of $X$ such that $\Psi(\omega_1)=\omega_2$? By an automorphism I mean a shift-commuting homeomorphism of $X$. The answer for a general minimal shift space is, I guess, negative as there are minimal shift spaces with two non-isomorphic ergodic measures. But what if $X$ posses only one ergodic measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strict ergodicity does not seem to change much, i.e. the answer is still negative, see the following theorem (W. Bułatek, J. Kwiatkowski, [Strictly ergodic Toeplitz flows with positive entropies and trivial centralizers](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm103/sm10323.pdf))

The exist a strictly ergodic Toeplitz flows with trivial centralizer.

By a Toeplitz flow we mean a closure of the orbit of a Toeplitz sequence, together with the shift map. Since any block appears on a Toeplitz sequence with some period, it follows that the unique invariant measure has full support, hence minimality.